# Redirect IP to domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, ip

Google search results are showing my pages as (ip)/mypage.html instead of https://www.mydomain.com/mypage.html. I believe the solution is to redirect the ip's to the domain. I've found many, very similar ways to do this, but none of them are working for me. I have an existing rule that redirects http to https. This is what my .htaccess file currently looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.111$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding a redirect won't change the links that Google believes works. Obviously Google has indexed some other page on the internet that links to your IP address.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your 2 rewrite conditions clash. They require http_host to be 11.11.11.111 and to be *.mydomain.com, at the same time. Just add an or like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.111$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now will Google adjust, or is there something else I need to do? All of my pages show up as (ip)/mypage.html.

Comment: A 301 should do that with google. Though I've never seen this with naked IP's, but I think it will work just fine. Make sure to check every now and than for the next few weeks.

Comment: What's the definition of a 301? Does the above solution count? My domain still won't show up in search results, only IP's.

Comment: Give it some time. Otherwise create an account at http://www.google.com/webmasters/

Comment: @Gerben, How to redirect `192.168.0.5/anyurl` to `https://example.com/anyurl` ?

Comment: Just a question: Isn't the HTTP_HOST header sent by the client? Is there a way to know for sure the client has requested to access the server directly over IPv4?

Answer (score 26):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteRule (.*) http://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Alter "111" to your IP

Comment: this worked better! Thanks. how about something like 111.111.111.111/* Can you update it or give a suggestion ?

Comment: thanks a lot! The gerban's answer didn't work for me... just because of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]` line

Answer (score 1):

update to willian's answer. you just need to replace the domain name (your-domain.io) from this snippet.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$
RewriteRule (.*) https://your-domain.io/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just a warning that this will force even internal hits to localhost 127.0.0.1 to also redirect, which could screw up monitoring services, which rely on being able to hit, for example, http://127.0.0.1/server-status?auto to see site status, resulting in errors. It's probably a better idea not to use regex and hardcode the IP address specifically to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there we had requirements to do this as well due to a trigger index in the main pub_html folder. These rules should mask the IP to the http (or https if you switch em), make non-www into www. This should also preserve subdomains. This is for (1) simple site sitting in the pub_html, so test with care if you have subdomain triggers or whatever else in your htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exampledomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^50\.28\.55\.76$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?exampledomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampledomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope it helps and works for ya'll. Thanks for the thoughts.