# How to add code for ip address of a website using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have written a code for Ip canonicaliozation in htaccess but it is not working when i am typing the ip address of the website and not directing to the site.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^50\.87\.211\.120 [nc,or]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

my websites ip address is 50.87.211.120.

But when i am writing the above code and typing the this ip address in the browser , it is not directing to the particular website.

Comment: The main question here is, does a request via that IP address even get to the location where this .htaccess is? Depending on your server setup, that might not be the case. If this file system path is only used in name-based VirtualHosts or something like that, then this might not be the case. And you can not redirect, if the request doesn’t even make it “into the directory” where your .htaccess is locacted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</pre>
```

As @CBroe mentioned in his comments for ipaddress, you can do that redirect at the domain cpanel itself (or) ensure the request reaches to the Document root folder first. Then add the rule.

```
Ref:
```

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/force-www-htaccess
[Redirect IP to domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985735/redirect-ip-to-domain)

Comment: _“Dollar symbol is missing at end of ip address / domain”_ – that would only matter if the input value would start with the search string, but contains additional characters after it - not the case for IP `50.87.211.120`

Comment: Thanks Updated the answer @CBroe